# Reference library problem in Release configuration on another computer

Tags: file, assemblies, windows-xp, ms-office, release

I get this error when I open a program I created in Windows Vista in C# with WPF on a computer with Windows XP:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

This is rather strange because MS Office 2007 is installed... and MS Office 2003 seems to be also installed. Could there be some sort of conflict between the two?

Also, .NET framework is installed up to 3.5!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is a very frustrating problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was installed first, .NET or MS Office 2007? If Office is installed before the .NET framework, the interop assemblies will not be installed in the GAC.

You could try downloading the PIA redistributable from MS and running it on your XP box: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=59daebaa-bed4-4282-a28c-b864d8bfa513&displaylang=en. This redistributable will load the MS Office interop assemblies into the GAC.

Comment: Office 2003 was installed first, then Office 2007 and then .NET framework.